# Django not loading images from media folder

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I have written a basic blog code. In that, I am trying to add images which have to be displayed as a cover image on the screen. But The images are not loading.

My code:

models.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models



class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template file:

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <!-- Blog Post -->
          <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.poster }}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              {{ post.publish }} by {{post.author}}
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
          <!-- Pagination -->
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">&larr; Older</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item disabled">
              <a class="page-link" href="#">Newer &rarr;</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
```

The error Log :

```
[01/Jul/2018 12:03:00] "GET /20161216_120931.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2515
[01/Jul/2018 12:12:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3659
[01/Jul/2018 12:12:17] "GET /static/blog/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /20151215_113251.jpg
[01/Jul/2018 12:12:17] "GET /20151215_113251.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2515
[01/Jul/2018 12:12:17] "GET /static/blog/blog-home.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /20161216_120931.jpg
[01/Jul/2018 12:12:17] "GET /20161216_120931.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2515
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

when I try to display the image, it is not being shown. What is the error here? How to rectify it? I have added media root in the settings.py file also. The images are being stored in media folder perfectly. But when i try to display the images, I am getting 404 error. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error log where?

Comment: I have added the error log. please check now

Comment: Are you sure `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is set properly?

Comment: Can you add relevant parts of `settings.py` file?

Comment: i have added the settings.py part also.please check

Comment: You still have some problem?

Comment: I'd that very same problem you are dealing with and I hope the answer below would have solved that.

Comment: That helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the url. From the logs, you can see the url to the image is just `/20161216_120931.jpg`, while there is no such image located at `http://localhost/20161216_120931.jpg`. The actual url should be `/media/20161216_120931.jpg`. You can add the url `/media` ahead to the filter `{{post.poster}}` like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- Blog Post -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.poster }}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          {{ post.publish }} by {{post.author}}
        </div>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or it would be better if you create a **method** to join the url for you. In your **models.py**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_image(self):
        return os.path.join('/media', self.poster.name)
```

And then after in your template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- Blog Post -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.get_absolute_image }}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          {{ post.publish }} by {{post.author}}
        </div>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: after adding pagination, whatever i add in the images, it is not being displayed. the code is not changed except i added pagination logic in the template

Comment: Why don't you use `{{ post.poster.url }}` ?

Comment: @AkhilReddy What are the logs after pagination. Are they still same?

Comment: @PankajSharma Thanks! It is working after your suggestion